# Detect iPhone accelerometer inactivity

Tags: iphone, uiaccelerometer

How do I check if the iPhone is not shaken for a specific time?

My app will support iOS 5.x and I heard accelerometer is depreciated in iOS 5.0. Can I detect inactivity in CoreMotion framework?

Please help me to solve this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just update a timestamp on each activity, and compare the old timestamp with the current time...?

Comment: @jorgen ya i get that. But how will i detect that the user has shaken the device. Is it possible in Coremotion framework?

Comment: I have used COre motion framework. Using CMMotionManager. But is gives me updates every second even if the device is kept idle